# Does this routable network include oneways information?

Tags: osm2po

I successfully imported osm road data using osm2po. I visualized the routable road network using Qgis. The table of the layer includes the following attributes: id|osm|name|osm_source|osm_target|clazz|flags|source|target|km|kmh|cost|reverse_cost|x1|y1|x2|y2
Does this routable network include oneways information or do I need to further process the data in order to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

analyze the reverse_cost column. If it doesn't equal the cost column and has a hight cost, then it is a one way.